# Proper functions and null gradient

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ proper map having a local but not global minimum, then $f$ must have another point where the gradient is $0\,$.

My attempt.

Suppose that the local minimum is achieved in $P=(x_0,y_0)$ and $f(P)=m$.
Since $f$ is proper then it has to be unbounded or from below or from above or both. Since $P$ is a local minimum there must exist another point $Q$ where $f(Q)<m$ but at the same time there exist $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(R)>f(P)$ for every $r\in B(P,\varepsilon)$.
From this point I'm unable to proceed. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the mountain pass theorem. $P$ is your high mountain valley. $Q$ is your destination on the plains below. Any way you leave the valley heading towards $Q$ will have a maximum somewhere. But most of those are tremendous climbs you don't want to attempt. The lowest exit from the valley is the one you want.

Comment: Now it is more clear. Could you give my a reference to this result (in the finite dimensional case?)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can google just as well as I can. By the means of proof I know, even though you are working with $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, you will need to consider all paths from $P$ to $Q$, which is an infinite-dimensional space, and it really helps to have a good understanding of topology, too. Once you show that there is a minimum high point among all exits from the valley, show that if the gradient at that pass were not $0$, there would be a path (varying from the "minimum" path by only a small change) with a lower high point.